# Calculating Jaccard for resampled sites only

Tags: r, vegan

I have a dataset where 40 sites were sampled for species presence absence in both 2017 and 2018. I am struggeling to find the best way of creating pairwise Jaccard distances between the sites.

I aim at getting pairwise comparisons between the same site within the two years. Eg. site 1 in 2017 and 2018, site 2 in 2017 and 2018. Is there a simple way of restricting the Jaccard calculations so it is only calculated when year is different and site is the same?

Wanted output:

```
                       jaccard
2017:1 vs 2018:1       0.2
2017:2 vs 2018:2       0.8
2017:3 vs 2018:3       0.5
2017:4 vs 2018:4       0.1
       .                .
       .                .
2017:40 vs 2018:40     0.6
```

Simluated data - My real data contain far more species than simulated here:

```
year <- c(rep(2017, 40), rep(2018, 40))
site <- c(rep(1:40,2))
sp1 <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=80)
sp2 <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=80) 
sp3 <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=80)

cbind(year, site, sp1,sp2,sp3)
```

When I calculate Jaccard I get a large matrix with all jaccard distances:

```
library(vegan)
vegdist(data, method = "jaccard", binary = TRUE)
```

Comment: Not in **vegan**. Check the **analogue** package.

Comment: Does this (using the dplyr package) deliver your desired results?
res_test = data_test %>% group_by(site) %>% do(dist = vegdist(.[c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3")], method = "jaccard", binary = TRUE))
res_test$dist

Comment: @TinglTanglBob I get an error when I enter your code: `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"`

Comment: i forgot to mention, that dplyr needs a data.frame instead of a matrix, sorry. I used the following data_test: data_test <- data.frame(year, site, sp1,sp2,sp3)

Comment: @TinglTanglBob Perfect, now it works! Thanks!